# How can I create a column that is the result of applying a piecewise function to another column?

Tags: r, dplyr

Here's a short example that I'll use to frame my problem:

```
river_tibble <- tibble(
  river_name = c("River 1", "River 2", "River 3", "River 4", "River 5"),
  river_width_1 = c(418, 1264, 744, 3403, 2089)
)
```

I have a piecewise function in mind. For example, I'd like to add a new column to my tibble (I assume using a `mutate` variant?) that is the result of a function that maps `river_width_1` values to `river_width_2` values as follows:

```
river_width_1 == 0 -> 0,
0 < river_width_1 < 500 -> 1,
500 <= river_width_1 < 1000 -> 2,
100 <= river_width_1 < 2000 -> 3,
200 <= river_width_1 -> 4
```

So the final result of this example would look like:

```
river_tibble <- tibble(
  river_name = c("River 1", "River 2", "River 3", "River 4", "River 5"),
  river_width_1 = c(418, 1264, 744, 3403, 2089),
  river_width_2 = c(1, 3, 2, 4, 4)
)
```

Is there a way to construct `river_width_2` with that set of conditionals using dplyr?

Comment: `river_tibble %>%
  mutate(river_width_2 = as.integer(cut(river_width_1, c(-Inf, 500, 1000, 2000, Inf))))
` or you can also use `case_when` and mention each condition one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `cut`

```
library(dplyr)

river_tibble %>% 
   mutate(river_width_2 = as.integer(cut(river_width_1, c(-Inf, 500, 1000, 2000, Inf))))

# river_name  river_width_1 river_width_2
#  <chr>              <dbl>         <int>
#1 River 1              418             1
#2 River 2             1264             3
#3 River 3              744             2
#4 River 4             3403             4
#5 River 5             2089             4
```

---

Or with `case_when`

```
river_tibble %>%
  mutate(river_width_2 = case_when(river_width_1 == 0 ~ 0 , 
                                   river_width_1 > 0 & river_width_1 < 500 ~ 1, 
                                   river_width_1 > 500 & river_width_1 < 1000 ~ 2, 
                                   river_width_1 > 1000 & river_width_1 < 2000 ~ 3, 
                                   TRUE ~ 4))
```